# Evaluating 2 sets of enums

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple console game based on the old mastermind game.
The game generates 4 random peg colours from a list of emuns; green, blue, red, purple, yellow, aqua and the user needs to guess the correct colours in the correct sequence. To help the user each time they enter an unsuccessful guess the game needs to return either black or white pegs. Black means they have a correct colour in the correct positon, white indicates they have a correct colour but in the wrong position.

I.e. 
If the random pegs were generated as

Position 1 = Green

Position 2 = Blue

Position 3 = Red

Position 4 = Purple

And user guess was

Position 1 = Blue

Position 2 = Red

Position 3 = Green

Position 4 = Purple

I would need to return 1 Black peg and 3 white pegs as Positon 4 the colours match and position 1-3 are the correct colours but in the wrong order.

In my code the colours are represented as enums assigned to a Peg class. I also have a PegContainer class that has 4 peg position properties of type Peg

I am instantiating a 2 new PegContainers objects, one for the random pegs (m_GameGeneratedPegs)  and one for the user’s guess (playerPegConatiner)

I have a UnsuccessfullGuess method that I have to extend to evaluate the m_GameGeneratedPegs and the playerPegConatiner objects and write the results back to the console

So I need to count the pegs that match both colour and position and return something like (using the example above)

1 X Black
3 X White

My current code looks like this

```
 #region Method
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the randomly generated PegContainer positions
    /// </summary>
    public void GeneratePegs()
    {
        m_GameGeneratedPegs = new PegContainer
                               {
                                   PegPosition1 = new Peg { Colour = GetRandomColourPeg() },
                                   PegPosition2 = new Peg { Colour = GetRandomColourPeg() },
                                   PegPosition3 = new Peg { Colour = GetRandomColourPeg() },
                                   PegPosition4 = new Peg { Colour = GetRandomColourPeg() }
                               };
        Output.WriteColourLine(ConsoleColor.Red, "DEBUG ONLY");
        m_ConsoleCommunicator.Write(string.Format("\n"));
        m_ConsoleCommunicator.Write(string.Format("Peg 1: {0}\nPeg 2: {1}\nPeg 3: {2}\nPeg 4: {3}\n\n",
            m_GameGeneratedPegs.PegPosition1.Colour,
            m_GameGeneratedPegs.PegPosition2.Colour,
            m_GameGeneratedPegs.PegPosition3.Colour,
            m_GameGeneratedPegs.PegPosition4.Colour));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the user guess
    /// </summary>
    public void ValidateGuess(PegContainer userGuess)
    {
        if (m_GameGeneratedPegs.Equals(userGuess))
            Susscess();
        UnsuccessfullGuess(m_GameGeneratedPegs, userGuess);
    }

    private PegColour GetRandomColourPeg()
    {
        PegColour colour = (PegColour)m_Rnd.Next(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(PegColour)).Length - 2);
        return colour;
    }

    private void Susscess()
    {
        m_ConsoleCommunicator.Write("You have won!!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// todo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameGeneratedGuess"> </param>
    /// <param name="userGuess"></param>
    private void UnsuccessfullGuess(PegContainer gameGeneratedGuess, PegContainer userGuess)
    {
       ////......
    }

    #endregion
```

Please help

Comment: Help how? What's your problem?

Comment: Here's some advice: Success is not spelled Susscess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'mon, algorithm design is the fun part! And this site is more for solving a specific programming issue, rather than, "Write my program's logic for me!" But if it helps, here are a couple things I'd suggest:

1. **Data Structure:** Instead of `PegContainer`, you might use a `Dictionary`, array or `List` of `Peg`s. That would let you use `for` loops or LINQ queries, rather than hardcoding all permutations of each guess position vs. each answer position. And then if you ever wanted to expand from 4 to 5 pegs, it'd take no effort.
2. **Algorithm:** I'd first check for exact matches, then exclude any exactly-matched pegs from consideration of partial matches. Otherwise, if the correct answer is four green pegs and the user guesses one green (or vice-versa), you may show a result score of one black and three white pegs, rather than a single black.
3. **Game Detail:** When you show the users the results, I'd show all the exact (black) matches first, and then show all of the partial (white) matches. If you don't, and you go position-by-position instead, the results could give away that, say, positions 1 and 3 are exact matches while 2 and 4 are partial.

Best of luck!